# outlook 2013 email keeps asking me to save an email address, how do I turn that off

Tags: microsoft-outlook

why does outlook keep asking me save every email address to an address book before I can send it, can I turn this setting off?  sometimes I just want to send a random email.

Comment: so you ... basically want to be able to send spam without having this question-dialog?

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you completely set up the account.

I could be wrong but that seems like the most probable cause